# Spark get exception within AnalysisException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have certain Spark Code, where I'm creating `DataFrame`s out of a given JSON Response from an API. This code also creates `DataFrame`s from the child JSON Objects and Arrays of this base response using a recursive algorithm.

But there are two certain scenarios, where `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException` is thrown, but the cause of it is different:

1. When trying to do `spark.sql(s"SELECT * FROM $viewName")` where the `viewName` hasn't yet been created using `createOrReplaceTempView` (See Exception 1)
2. When trying to explode an Empty JSON Array. (eg. `{"RELATED": []}`) (See Exception 2)

While I'm handling all exceptions using the below `try/catch` block:

```
try {
    // val existing = spark.sql(s"SELECT * FROM $viewName")

    // Some more Spark Code 

    // val temp = df.select(explode($"${arr.name}").as(arr.name)).select(s"${arr.name}.*")
}
catch {
    case e: AnalysisException =>
        e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Exception 1:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: SET_TYPE_ID; line 1 pos 14
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.resolveRelation(Analyzer.scala:683)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:713)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:706)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:706)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:652)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:31)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:54)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:52)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:63)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:54)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:52)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:63)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:54)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:52)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:63)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at JsonParser$.delayedEndpoint$JsonParser$1(JsonParser.scala:24)
    at JsonParser$delayedInit$body.apply(JsonParser.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at JsonParser$.main(JsonParser.scala:8)
    at JsonParser.main(JsonParser.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'set_type_id' not found in database 'default';
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalog$class.requireTableExists(ExternalCatalog.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.InMemoryCatalog.requireTableExists(InMemoryCatalog.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.InMemoryCatalog.getTable(InMemoryCatalog.scala:326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.ExternalCatalogWithListener.getTable(ExternalCatalogWithListener.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.lookupRelation(SessionCatalog.scala:706)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:728)
    ... 90 more
```

Exception 2:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(RELATED)`;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedStar.expand(unresolved.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$buildExpandedProjectList$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:978)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$buildExpandedProjectList$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:976)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$buildExpandedProjectList(Analyzer.scala:976)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:904)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$9.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:899)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1.apply(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:899)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:756)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:3412)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1358)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:60)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:63)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:54)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:52)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:63)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:54)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:52)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:63)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:54)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:52)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$1.apply(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:48)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:63)
    at JsonParser$$anonfun$recurse$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at JsonParser$.recurse(JsonParser.scala:57)
    at JsonParser$.delayedEndpoint$JsonParser$1(JsonParser.scala:24)
    at JsonParser$delayedInit$body.apply(JsonParser.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at JsonParser$.main(JsonParser.scala:8)
    at JsonParser.main(JsonParser.scala)
```

Is there any way to get the actual Exception that happened within [other than getting the exception message and finding certain string keywords] (eg. `NoSuchTableException` in  Exception 1), so that I can handle exceptions in a cleaner way?